# How to remove edges from JButton after border radius?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingbuilder

Finally it's done to make rounded corners for JButton, i'm tired to remove the edges that show after border radius without using transparent images

Screenshot of JButton

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UxyX.jpg]

here's the code

```
        JButton button = new JButton("SIGN IN");
        Color borderColor = Color.decode("#2c3338");
        button.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20, borderColor));
        button.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 11));
        button.setBackground(Color.decode("#ea4c88"));
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        button.setBounds(135, 233, 280, 44);
        container.add(button);
```

```
public class RoundedBorder implements Border {

    private int radius;
    private Color borderColor;

    public RoundedBorder(int Radius, Color BorderColor) {
        radius = Radius;
        borderColor = BorderColor;
    }

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(radius, radius, radius, radius);
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics Graphics, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Graphics2D Graphics2D = (Graphics2D) Graphics.create();
        Graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Graphics2D.setColor(borderColor);
        Graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        Graphics2D.drawRoundRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, radius, radius);
        Graphics2D.dispose();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Here is a similar question and answer, _https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698092/design-button-in-java-like-in-css_

Comment: Try _[Graphics#fillRoundRect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRoundRect(int,int,int,int,int,int))_, rather than _setBackground_.

Comment: would you provide the code using any text storage site like pastebin, justpasteit, etc..

Comment: It's just one method.

Comment: You don’t - border doesn’t/isn’t meant to fill. Instead you need to fake it; for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386749/how-to-add-to-this-round-button-metal-background-in-java/13389263#13389263) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76167851/button-corners-dont-get-painted-over-by-borders-they-are-moved-outwards-instea/76168325#76168325)

Comment: Need to make it without downloading any externals.

Comment: @MohamedGharib No "downloaded externals" in either of my examples - just plain old code

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm sorry but i don't understand what you're trying to say, please use text storage website like pastebin, justpasteit, etc... if you can modify my code

Comment: @MohamedGharib And no - that's not how SO works.  This question has been asked and answered many times before.  The simple answer to your question is - you can't do what you want with `Border`, it's not designed to do what you want, you need to change your approach and either create a custom class which extends from `JButton` and override it's `paintComponent` method or implement a custom `ButtonUI` delegate.  Both methods are demonstrated in the two examples I've linked and the answer I've already provided

Answer (score 1):

`Border` isn't meant to "fill" and based on the order of the paint chain, it's called AFTER the background is painted.

A possible solution is to "fake" it instead, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.ipadx = 40;
            add(new RoundedButton("Sign In"), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class RoundedButton extends JButton {

        private Color borderColor = Color.decode("#2c3338");
        private int radius = 20;

        public RoundedButton(String text) {
            super(text);
            //button.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20, borderColor))/;
            setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 11));
            setBackground(Color.decode("#ea4c88"));
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            setFocusPainted(false);
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            setBorderPainted(false);
            setOpaque(false);
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getInsets() {
            return new Insets(radius, radius, radius, radius);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, radius, radius);
            g2d.setColor(borderColor);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
            g2d.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, radius, radius);
            g2d.dispose();
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Please also note, the simple use of `GridBagLayout` in the example, which deals with calculating the size and position of the button, the addition of the `iPadx` constraint to increase the width of the button and obviously, the overridden `getInsets` method of the `JButton`.

Also not the order in which the button is painted, you MUST paint the background BEFORE calling `super.paintComponent`, as the super method will paint the text

[Button corners don't get painted over by borders, they are moved outwards instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76167851/button-corners-dont-get-painted-over-by-borders-they-are-moved-outwards-instea/76168325#76168325) demonstrates an alternative which can be used to change ANY (or all) `JButton`, rather then needing to use a dedicate class.  This example simple creates a new `ButtonUI` which can be applied to ANY instance of `JButton` to change the way in which it's painted, arguably making it a better solution where you already have a pre-existing UI.