# How can I change the button pressing animation in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, animation, button

I am making a Java Swing program, and created a special class for creating a customized button with rounded corners and a drop shadow. However, when I click it, it just uses its default animation, which is completely off with the button's look. How can I change that?

Here is the code with the class i created:

```
    class RoundedButton extends JButton {

        public RoundedButton(String text){
            setText(text);
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            int x=0, y=0, width=getWidth(), height=getHeight();
            Area area = new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height, 10, 10));
            g2d.setColor(new Color(70, 70, 70));
            g2d.fill(area);
            area.subtract(new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height-4, 10, 10)));
            g2d.setColor(new Color(60, 60, 60));
            g2d.fill(area);
            g2d.dispose();
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

    }
```

So far I've tried to add a mouse listener to the button, and make it so that it reruns the paintComponent function differently, changing the button's look accordingly, but even though it worked, it has quite a lot of delay, and still doesn't get rid of the old animation.

```
    applyButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
           applyButton.setClicked(true);
           applyButton.paintComponent(applyB.getGraphics());
           super.mousePressed(e);
       }

       @Override
       public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
           applyButton.setClicked(false);
           applyButton.paintComponent(applyB.getGraphics());
           super.mouseReleased(e);
       }
   });
```

```
    public RoundedButton(String text){
        setText(text);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    boolean c=false;

    public void setClicked(boolean c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int x=0, y=0, width=getWidth(), height=getHeight();
        if(!c) {
            Area area = new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height, 10, 10));
            g2d.setColor(new Color(70, 70, 70));
            g2d.fill(area);
            area.subtract(new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height - 4, 10, 10)));
            g2d.setColor(new Color(60, 60, 60));
            g2d.fill(area);
            g2d.dispose();
        }else{
            Area area = new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height, 10, 10));
            g2d.setColor(new Color(50, 50, 50));
            g2d.fill(area);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You REALLY should be making use of the `ButtonUI` as a starting point for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339013/why-paintcomponent-is-defined-on-jcomponent/47341727#47341727), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76151080/how-do-i-extend-jbutton-but-modify-actionperformed/76151919#76151919), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76167851/button-corners-dont-get-painted-over-by-borders-they-are-moved-outwards-instea/76168325#76168325)

Comment: Always remember [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)!